# Get direction of normal without matrix inversion

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d

I am building a 3D engine and I want it to calculate normals for triangles automatically.

The user creates a model that is made of triangles. Every triangle is made of three points in the space, and every model has its own central point. Here is some pseudo code:

```
class Triangle
{
    point p[3];
    Vector normal;
}

class Model
{
    List<Triangle> triangles;
    Point centralPoint;
}
```

I know that a normal can be evaluated with a cross product of the triangle vertices

```
normal = (p[0]-p[2])X(p[0]-p[1])
```

But I want the normal to point from the central point, out from the model. I can verify this by creating a base

```
B = ( (p[0]-p[2]) (p[0]-p[1]) normal )
```

Giving me the equation

```
B*x = centralPoint
```

And if the third element of vector x is negative, means that my normal is pointing to the direction that I want. The problem here is that I have to define a matrix and calculate its inverse, just to make sure that this number is negative! Seems like an unnecessary performance thief. Is there any shortcut that I can take here?

Comment: I think testing the sign of the scalar product `p[0]-central` and `normal` should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not very clearly formulated, but it seems that you need to know on which side of the plane $\{\, x\mid x\cdot N=0 \}$ parallel to your triangle, and passing through the origin, is situated your central point$~p$ . Here $N$ is the normal vector to that plane. This is easy: just evaluate the scalar product $p\cdot N$ and if it is positive then $p$ is on the same side as $N$ is, and on the opposite side if $p\cdot N<0$.

Maybe you wanted the plane of the triangle itself (but that is not what your computation using the basis $B$ would give); in that case the equation is $\{\, x\mid x\cdot N=p[0]\cdot N \}$, and you should take the scalar product $(p-p[0])\cdot N$ to know on which side $p$ is situated.